# How to work with subcontractors in DevOps when you do NOT want to share all of your code?

Tags: git, azure-devops

There ara a project repository in DevOps. (git)
A subcontractor will develop a sub modul/function in this project.
I want to set visible only the required code for subcontractor.
Are there any solition in DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

create a separate repo (use it as a submodule, perhaps). git (and azure devops is just that) cant do security inside repo.

Comment: I am new in git. If I create separeted repo, how can I merge into the main repo?

Comment: you can use submodules, or just copy folders over when its done

Comment: Another option would be to publish the seperate repo as a package to an Azure Artifacts feed. Then you can use it as a NuGet package in the other repo.

Comment: yeah, but you still have to create a separate repo to maintain code for that package, right? :)